# Image and preimage in complex planes

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $S = \{ x+iy \mid 0 \leq x \leq 1,\;  0 \leq y \leq 1 \} \subseteq \Bbb{C}$, and let $f(z) = \exp(-\pi iz)$.

Find **(a)** the image $f(S)$ and **(b)** the preimage $f^{-1}(1)$.

This was how I approached it.

Let $w = \exp(\pi y)\bigl(\cos(-\pi x) + \sin(-\pi x)\bigr)$. Since $0 \leq y \leq 1$, $\exp(\pi y)$ is in $[-1, 0]$ and since $0 \leq x \leq 1$, $\cos(-\pi x)$ is in $[-1, 0]$. But, how do I find the image and preimage from there?

Comment: You wrote *preimage* but then $f(1)$.  I took the liberty of changing that to a **pre**image $f^{-1}(1)$.  Please correct it if it's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

a) Let $\partial S$ the boundary of $S$. What is $f(\partial S)$ ?

b) $$f(z)=1\iff e^{-\pi iz}=1\iff e^{\pi y}e^{-\pi ix}=1\iff e^{\pi y}\cos(\pi x)=1\ \ \text{and}\ \ e^{\pi y}\sin(\pi x)=0\iff ...$$

**Picture added**

This is $f(\partial S)$.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the prompt response. But (b) was asking for the preimage f^{-1}(1). Couldn't type that out in latex.

Comment: It's exactly what I did ! By definition $$f^{-1}(\{1\})=\{z\mid f(z)=1\}$$

Comment: the image part is still confusing. How do I find the boundary of S?

Comment: $$\partial S=\{x\mid x\in[0,1]\}\cup\{1+iy\mid y\in[0,1]\}\cup\{x+i\mid x\in[0,1]\}\cup\{iy\mid y\in[0,1]\}$$

Comment: @J.R. Have a look at the edits that I made to learn how to use $\LaTeX$ markup on this site.  You can click "edit" just below the question.

Comment: @SammyBlack, many thanks. That certainly comes in handy.

Comment: @Surb, is the image a straight line?

Comment: No, it's a half crown. I'll add the picture in 2 min

Comment: @Surb, I appreciate the pictorial form of it. But then again, mathematically, how do we deduce that?